# Let $f(x)=\frac{9^x}{9^x+3}$. Evaluate $\sum_{i=1}^{1995}f(\frac{i}{1996})$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, contest-math

> Let $f(x)=\frac{9^x}{9^x+3}$. Evaluate $\sum_{i=1}^{1995}f(\frac{i}{1996})$.

This problem seems extremely hard until you find out that $f(x)+f(1-x)=1$ and you can then evalute $f(\frac{1}{1996})+f(\frac{1995}{1996}) =1, \dots, f(\frac{998}{1996})+f(1-\frac{998}{1996})=f(\frac12)+f(\frac12)=1 \implies f(\frac{998}{1996})=\frac12$. Thus the sum is just $997+\frac12$. My question is that how can one see something like this from a question like this without having gone through some contest math training where these kinds of "tricks" are taught. Is there some kind of tell here from which one can find this "property"?

Comment: I believe the construction of these problems is based on tricks, so I don't know if there are general principles to solving these problems without observing the trick.

Comment: This seems absurd. Mathematics shouldn't be about these magical tricks.

Comment: I neither disagree nor agree with your assertion. A lot of mathematics start out being just tricks until people find unifying principles. Then tricks become theories.

Comment: Also, the posted problem is a math contest problem (i.e. a puzzle). So, why is it absurd that it relies on a trick?

Comment: I agree with the fact that through investigation and thinking the so called tricks might eventually lead to theorems, but for some people these competitions might be very serious and the fact that not everyone has access to these special training where they will teach you tricks like this and still these kind of simple but tricky questions are used to qualify people is a serious issue.

Comment: There is no special training that will tell you every trick. There are some famous and well-known tricks, which appear in books and sites dedicated to puzzle solving and contest math. If you want a more intuitive solution to this particular question then someone might be able to help you. But there is no magic solve-every-problem strategy.

Comment: @Nate I don't really understand your complaint. Even in research, not all tools are made available to the public. Some research groups have their own methods that are not easily accessible to other groups, but no one is complaining about that. Also, those who take math competition seriously should already know that they are being evaluated for speed, accuracy, and whether they can find the slick solution. It's part of the game. Even so, I don't think being successful or not in math competitions has too much bearing on whether you will be a successful mathematician or not.

Comment: General comment: Looking for — and exploiting — symmetry is a powerful technique in most parts of mathematics.

Comment: I just want to ask, is this a Math Olympiad question?

Answer (score 1):

There are two aspects which can lead us from
\begin{align*}
f(x)=\frac{9^x}{9^x+3}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
to the functional equation $f(x)+f(1-x)=1$.

> *Simplification:* We can reduce the number of occurrences of $x$ in (1) by factoring out $9^x=3^{2x}$. We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> f(x)=\frac{9^x}{9^x+3}=\frac{1}{1+3^{1-2x}}\tag{2}
> \end{align*}
> *Known pattern:* The right hand side of (2) is a well known pattern which admits the following relationship
> \begin{align*}
> \frac{1}{1+a}+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{a}}=\frac{1}{1+a}+\frac{a}{1+a}=1\tag{3}
> \end{align*}

The convenient relationship (3) applies to (2) with a nice twist of
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{a}=\frac{1}{3^{1-2x}}=3^{-(1-2x)}=3^{1-2(1-x)}
\end{align*}
from which
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{f(x)+f(1-x)=1}
\end{align*}
follows.